# How to edit named destination in PDF file using iTextSharp with C#?

Tags: c#, itext

Here I want to edit the already exist named destination in PDF file using C# with iTextSharp.dll.

Here I am showing sample PS script.

**OLD:**

```
[/Dest /bmkaff1 /View [/FitR 59 516 435 504] /DEST pdfmark
```

**Updated:**

```
[/Dest /bmkaff1 /View [/XYZ 59 516 0] /DEST pdfmark
```

**PDF Dictionary Screen shot:**

[image]

**Original PDF File**

[image]

**Updated PDF file**

[image]

**Note:**

*Updated PDF file is generated by updating the PS file*

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ Alexis Pigeon see below i got answer for my question.

Comment: Great! That very nice of you to have followed up on that issue, it'll be valuable for future readers who might face the same problem. Remember it's considered a good practice to accept answers that solved your problem, even if it was yourself who provided the answer.

Comment: @ Alexis Pigeon, Thank u Alexis, I am referred following link to collect ideas, [http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html] and [http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#getNamedDestination()]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution for my question.

First I am using `GetNamedDestination()` method to read the namded destionation and then checking with condition and then editing the named destination values.

**Here my C# code:**

```
string pdfFilePath = @"D:\Raja\Testing\AuthorQuery\xxx.pdf";
string dPDFFile = @"D:\Raja\Testing\AuthorQuery\YYY.pdf";

PdfReader pdfR = new PdfReader(pdfFilePath);
Dictionary<object, PdfObject> nDest = new Dictionary<object, PdfObject>();

nDest = pdfR.GetNamedDestination();

List<object> nDesColl = new List<object>();

nDesColl.Clear();

foreach (KeyValuePair<object, PdfObject> sEntry in nDest)
{
    PdfArray pArr = (PdfArray)sEntry.Value;
    if(pArr.ArrayList.Count== 6)
    {
        if (pArr[1].ToString() == "/FitR")
        {
nDesColl.Add(sEntry.Key);
        }
    }
}

if (nDesColl.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (object keyVal in nDesColl)
    {
        PdfNumber pNo = new PdfNumber(0);
        PdfArray pArr = (PdfArray)nDest[keyVal];
        pArr[1] = PdfName.XYZ;
        pArr[4] = (PdfObject)pNo;
        pArr.ArrayList.RemoveAt(5);
        PdfObject fVal = (PdfObject)pArr;
        nDest[keyVal] = fVal;
    }
}

using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfR, new FileStream(dPDFFile, FileMode.Create)))
{
}
```